# App is getting started again after launcher click even when it is already running

Tags: android, launcher

I have the problem that my App is starting again if the user clicks the launcher icon even if it is already running. I used `singleTaks` for that Activity and as many Stackoverflow Answers said -> This should solve the problem - but it doesnt.

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.ActivitySplash"
    android:launchMode="singleTask">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

As you can see i did define the `launchMode` to be `singleTask`. I open the App. Navigate to Screen X (I even could stay on the Startscreen, has the same effect) and now i press the home button. When i now press the launcher icon again the already running app does not pop up or is getting resumed (call it as you wish). Instead the App is completly started new.

How can i prevent that behaviour, if `singleTask` isnt working?

Comment: You cannot control whether your Activity will be destroyed once you leave it. Android OS takes care of that, and if too much time passes or something else requires the resources (RAM especially) your Activity will get destroyed.

Comment: The time is irrelevant for my problem since it is happening in seconds. I tested Whatsapp to compare it with my app behaviour. Whats app is always resuming the App if it is already running. Even if it is in background for hours. My App isnt even resuming, when it is in the background for seconds.

Comment: Well, whatsapp probably uses the `savedInstanceState` parameter in their `onCreate()` and `onResume` :)

Comment: As @Perroloco answered the solution is `singleTop` other stackoverflow answers are then outdated which are telling to use `singleTask`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with SingleTop:

> if the target task already has an existing instance of the activity
>   at the top of its stack, that instance will receive the new intent (in
>   an onNewIntent() call); a new instance is not created. In other
>   circumstances — for example, if an existing instance of the
>   "singleTop" activity is in the target task, but not at the top of the
>   stack, or if it's at the top of a stack, but not in the target task —
>   a new instance would be created and pushed on the stack.

Comment: That is it. Thank you.